# Firefox fullscreen toolbar won't hide (only after hovering it with mouse)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i have an addon button in the toolbar which toggles a panel (show / hide).

if i go into fullscreen - the toolbar hides. 
Now i move the mouse to the top edge - toolbars appear.
i click the button - the panel appears
i click another button in the panel and call a function.
at the end of the function hide() is called on that panel and it disappears. 
the problem now is, that the toolbar stays visible until i touch the toolbar with the mousecursor and move it away again instead of disappearing with the panel. this is annoying. 
is there a workaround for this issue? a command to hide the toolbar from the addon code?

thx.

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •**the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: We generally try to provide answers that are tested and working. If we are going to try to verify our solution works for *you* it is *MUCH* easier to do so if we have your code to start from rather than having to make it all up. To do so, we each have to first duplicate the problem you are having then find a solution. Not having source code in the form of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) makes helping you a *LOT* more work. Without such code there is less incentive to find an answer for you.